# Nginx redirect one path to another

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I can't find a solution that works.

A website has switched CMS services, but has the same domain, how do I set up an nginx rewrite for a single page?

E.g.

### Old Page

http://sitedomain.co.uk/content/unique-page-name

### New page

http://sitedomain.co.uk/new-name/unique-page-name

**Please note**, I don't want everything within the content page to be redirected, but literally just the url mentioned above. I have about 9 redirects to set up, non of which fit in a pattern.

Thanks!

Edit: I found this solution, which seems to be working, except for the fact that it redirects without a slash:

```
if ( $request_filename ~ content/unique-page-name/ ) {
   rewrite ^ http://sitedomain.co.uk/new-name/unique-page-name/? permanent;
}
```

But this redirects to:

`http://sitedomain.co.uknew-name/unique-page-name/`

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Direct quote from [Pitfalls and Common Mistakes: Taxing Rewrites](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#Taxing_Rewrites):

> By using the return directive we can completely avoid evaluation of regular expression.

Please use `return` instead of `rewrite` for permanent redirects. Here's my approach to this use-case...

```
location = /content/unique-page-name {
  return 301 /new-name/unique-page-name;
}
```

Comment: It's definitely more readable. Will this also retain any queries that were on the original URL?

Comment: Am I right in thinking that using `if` statements in nginx is bad? Would this still be better practice than using the rewrite method?

Comment: Using `if` along with return directive is perfectly fine. See http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil . Yes, IMO, it's better than using rewrite.

Comment: Why `return ...` instead of `rewrite ... ... permanent;` for the permanent redirects? Is there a reason why that that should be preferred? In that current answer there's no longer a `if` statement, was that why?

Comment: Please see the quoted text in the answer.

Comment: This would be valuable if nginx would internally change the path, not informing web browser about 301.

Answer (score 29):

Ideally you shouldn't use if statements if you can avoid it. Something like this could work (untested).

```
location ~ /content/(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^ /new-name/$1?$args permanent;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that catch everything within the content directory? I only want to redirect the individual item. For example, I have another item in the content directory, but I need it redirecting to .../another-new-name/unique-page-name2

Comment: I've solved it. Turns out it redirecting correctly, but the script is was hitting was mangling the URL after.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the question. I thought you wanted only the content part to change. The principle remains the same. I'm glad its working for you.

Comment: No problem, thanks for the help though, I'll definitely need to use that in the future.

Answer (score 18):

I used the following solution:

```
rewrite ^(/content/unique-page-name)(.*)$   http://sitedomain.co.uk/new-name/unique-page-name/$2 permanent;
```

Works a treat.

Answer (score 14):

For me it worked without the equals sign like this:

```
location /old-url {
  return 301 /new-url;
}
```

Comment: You don't need the location block at all. Just use `rewrite`. See @SteveEdison's answer.

Comment: @PKHunter According to NGINX best practices actually return 301 is the best approach to follow. https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#taxing-rewrites

Answer (score 0):

it works for me.

```
server {
  listen 80;

  location = /content/unique-page-name {
    return 301 http://sitedomain.co.uk/new-name/unique-page-name;
  }
}
```

Comment: Using the full path of return line worked for me. However, in my case I'm using two different domains, so not sure that is relevant.