# Effect of trailing question mark (?) in nginx rewrite directive's replacement URI

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I'm trying to understand the difference between `rewrite ^/search/(.*)$ /search.php?q=$1` and `rewrite ^/search/(.*)$ /search.php?q=$1?`. The difference is the trailing `?` in the replacement URI.

If the request URI is `/search/apple?opt=123` then how are the URI rewritten differently?

I'm guessing for `rewrite ^/search/(.*)$ /search.php?q=$1` it will be `/search.php?q=apple&opt=123` and for `rewrite ^/search/(.*)$ /search.php?q=$1?` it will be `/search.php?q=apple`? But I'm not sure.

Comment: Possible answer https://serverfault.com/a/973708/102173

Comment: @PothiKalimuthu mine's a bit more complex case.

Comment: Your guess mentioned in OP is correct.

Comment: @PothiKalimuthu ok thx!

Answer (score 3):

As per https://nginx.org/r/rewrite...

> If a replacement string includes the new request arguments, the
> previous request arguments are appended after them. If this is
> undesired, putting a question mark at the end of a replacement string
> avoids having them appended

Here's the bare minimal code to test this scenario...

```
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
events {}

http {
    server {
        rewrite ^/search/(.*)$ /search.php?q=$1 permanent;
        # rewrite ^/search/(.*)$ /search.php?q=$1? permanent;
    }
}
```

Permanent flag is added only for testing. We can save the above code as `nginx.conf` and start Nginx. `curl` output for the above code confirms `/search/apple?opt=123` will redirect to `/search.php?q=apple&opt=123`.

Similarly, for the second rewrite condition...

```
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
events {}

http {
    server {
        # rewrite ^/search/(.*)$ /search.php?q=$1 permanent;
        rewrite ^/search/(.*)$ /search.php?q=$1? permanent;
    }
}
```

`curl` output for the above code confirms `/search/apple?opt=123` will redirect to `/search.php?q=apple`.

So,

> If the request URI is /search/apple?opt=123 then how are the URI rewritten differently?

> I'm guessing for rewrite ^/search/(.*)$ /search.php?q=$1 it will be
> /search.php?q=apple&opt=123 and for rewrite ^/search/(.*)$
> /search.php?q=$1? it will be /search.php?q=apple? But I'm not sure.

You are right and this is the expected result.