# Nginx: Add/inject the same root path to all rewrites?

Tags: nginx

I currently host content on the following paths:

```
http://oldsite/samples/content/
http://oldsite/samples/ql
http://oldsite/samples/api/content/plans/
http://oldsite/samples/api/streams/map.xml
...
```

I have a new site coming up which will eventually serve that content under:

```
http://newsite/content/
http://newsite/ql
http://newsite/api/content/plans/
http://newsite/api/streams/map.xml
...
```

Meaning the **samples** subpath will be removed.

So basically the inverted version of:

[Nginx redirect one path to another](https://serverfault.com/questions/548591/nginx-redirect-one-path-to-another)

During this transition my plan is to *rewrite* those path using nginx. Currently I have this configured:

**/etc/nginx.conf.d/sandbox.conf**

server {

```
    #listen 80;
    #listen [::]:80;

    listen 8082 default_server;
    listen [::]:8082 default_server;


    location / {
         proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
         
         location /content/ {
            rewrite 301 /samples/content/;
         }

         location /ql {
            rewrite 301 /samples/ql;
         }

         location /api/content/plans/ {
            rewrite 301 /samples/api/content/plans/;
         }

         location /api/streams/map.xml {
            rewrite 301 /samples/api/streams/map.xml;
         }
    }
```

}

But is there a more clean way to do this - using some regex/wildcard pattern so I don't have to write out each path?

Also if I instead do:

**/etc/nginx.conf.d/sandbox.conf**

server {

```
    #listen 80;
    #listen [::]:80;

    listen 8082 default_server;
    listen [::]:8082 default_server;

    location / {
         proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
         
         location /samples/content/ {
            rewrite 301 /content/;
         }

         location /samples/ql {
            rewrite 301 /ql;
         }

         location /samples/api/content/plans/ {
            rewrite 301 /api/content/plans/;
         }

         location /samples/api/streams/map.xml {
            rewrite 301 /api/streams/map.xml;
         }
    }
```

}

I get:

```
$ curl localhost:8082/content
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

and access log:

```
, request: "GET /content HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8082"
2021/03/15 10:05:18 [error] 81448#81448: *4 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/content" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /content HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8082"
```

Where bypassing nginx I get:

```
curl localhost:8080/samples/content
Hello!
```

Comment: This nginx configuration seems to be doing rewrites in the _opposite_ direction, _adding_ `/samples` to the URL, but you said that you want to remove it. What is going on?

Comment: I have updated the post. If I "reverse" the location I get another error it seems its using /usr/share/nginx/html/ as root.

Answer (score 0):

The following will remove prefix `/samples` from all redirected URLs:

```
location ~ /samples(.*) {
    return 301 $1;
}
```

If you want to use another domain, use:

```
return 301 https://new.example.com$1;
```

In the `location` block.