# redash configured behind nginx conf file with server location is duplicating the url path

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

My nginx conf file entry for redash

```
location /redash/ {
    sub_filter ="/" ="/redash/";
    sub_filter ="/static/ ="/redash/static/;
    sub_filter ="/ldap/ ="/redash/ldap/;
    sub_filter ="/saml/login ="/redash/saml/login;
    sub_filter url(/static url(/redash/static;
    sub_filter_once off;
    sub_filter_types application/javascript text/css text/xml text/javascript application/json text/plain;

    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header SCRIPT_NAME /redash;

    proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:5000;
}
```

This work for the server but when i refresh my page.
On first access, i see url like this
http://localhost/redash/

but on sub-sequent refresh redash gets appended, After multiple refresh, url looks like below.

http://localhost/redash/redash/redash/redash/redash/redash/redash/redash/redash/

Is there anything wrong with my redash configuration?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am trying to configure redash in nginx on non root path "/redash/" and expecting the application to be accesible on "http://localhost/redash/" but here in the url "/redash/" gets appended multiple times after login. If i refresh the page, it add more and url look like below

http://localhost/redash/redash/redash/redash/redash/redash/redash/redash/redash/

Comment: that is not thhe [recommended setup](https://redash.io/help/open-source/admin-guide/https-ssl-setup) for redash nor the suggested [docker setup](https://gist.github.com/arikfr/64c9ff8d2f2b703d4e44fe9e45a7730e) so i dont know what you follow but the official guide not at this moment ;)

Comment: Well, i am trying to set redash on non root path. Link which you have shared, has the details of hosting it on root path.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nginx redirect one path to another](https://serverfault.com/questions/548591/nginx-redirect-one-path-to-another)

Comment: No, It does not help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151684/discussion-between-djdomi-and-raj).